# finite/non-finite verb = conjugated/non-conjugated verb

Tags: terminology, verbs, lexical-semantics, conjugation

Are those terms totally interchangeable in all contexts (finite = conjugated) (non-finite = conjugated) or are there slight meaning differences?

Comment: Depending on the language there can be multiple non-finite forms of a verb, usually including some or all of the gerunds, infinitives and participles. A verb form is said to be finite if it expresses a tense. But maybe also if it expresses an aspect. I'm sure whether other verbal categories such as mood and voice would affect whether a verb form is called finite or non-finite.

Comment: Could it be said that non-finite means 'this verb can't actually be used as a (main) verb'?

Comment: Close. Generally "non-finite" means a verb that's less verby than a main verb. English verbs have two finite (_goes, went_) and three non-finite forms (_go, gone, going_). Respectively, these are the 3rd Person Singular Present Tense, the Past Tense, the Infinitive, the Perfect Passive Participle, and the Present Active Participle forms of the verb. Finite verb forms can be main verbs in main clauses; nonfinite verb forms only occur in subordinate clauses. Finite verb forms require a subject; nonfinite verb forms frequently appear with implied or indefinite subjects. And so on.

Comment: Oh, and _conjugation_ only refers to inflections that occur in [paradigms](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html), which are characteristic of Indo-European amalgamating (fusional) inflected languages like Latin. Agglutinative inflections like Turkish don't occur in paradigms, but still practice finite/non-finite distinction. A better general term would be "inflected/uninflected".

Comment: Hmm, Georgian is not Indo European and is agglutinating but discussions of its very tricky verbs usually use the terms *paradigm* and *conjugation*, as well as some unique terms like *screeve*.

Comment: @hippietrail: Georgian is at least partly fusional, hence "conjugating": the 1pl and 2pl can be decomposed into the person and number affixes, but 3pl can't.

Comment: Yes Georgian is a great example of where the distinction between inflection and agglutination breaks down. But I wouldn't use that as proof of terminology use.

Comment: @jlawler: Are you saying *go* in *they go home* is "non-finite?

Comment: I'm saying that _go_ in _they go home_ **might** be non-finite; you can't tell from the clause or the verb form. It depends what it can alternate with. _It's important that they go home_ alternates with _It's important that he go home_, so it's a non-finite verb form (used in a finite clause, note -- a subject is required and can't be deleted). But _I don't remember when they go home_ alternates with _I don't remember when he goes home_, so it's finite by both criteria.

Comment: @jlawler: Okay, then you use a very unusual definition of "finite" that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: There's several more criteria, depending on the language and the details of inflection. Those are the tests for English; other languages have different systems. There is no universal sense of "verb finiteness"; _finite_ is a technical term, and like all such, may be appropriate in some cases and not in others.

Comment: I wonder why you say that Turksh do not occur by paradigm? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these terms originate in Indo-European grammar, I will focus on Indo-European languages; these names may not apply as well to non-Indo-European languages.

---

The **conjugation** of a verb can mean two things:

1.) All the finite forms of a verb.

2.) All the inflected forms of a verb, including non-finite forms, like the infinitive and participles. I believe this usage is more common.

A **finite** form of a verb is one that has an ending; conventionally, the suffixes used to form infinitives (what's in a name?) and participles are not considered endings, although one might question the rationale behind this.

A verb **ending** is normally that part of a verb which expresses the features person and number (and usually mood). That is, a non-ending normally cannot express person or number or mood; but an ending *can* express more than person and number and mood (such as tense). You could say endings that express more than person, number, and mood are a contraction of some suffix with an ending, like the Latin imperfect (e.g. *stabam*, "I stood"), which is either analysed as *present stem + imperfect suffix -ba- + ending* (sta-ba-m), or as *present stem + imperfect ending* (sta-bam). We *usually* say the tense is included in the ending in such cases, of which there are many, but in other situations it is more practical to treat the suffix or contraction as a separate morpheme.

Strictly speaking, an **ending / finite form** is a kind of **inflected form** (finite inflexion), and an **inflected form** is a kind of **suffixed form**. Often, but not always, we use *suffix* to mean "non-inflexional suffix", because we already call inflected forms "inflected"— although inflected forms are also said to have inflexional suffixes in some contexts. "Inflected forms" normally does include all finite forms / endings.

**Tense** is a difficult concept of which different people use different definitions. An ending can be said to express tense, although there are endings that do not express tense. The forms of the Greek optative, for example, are always finite, but they never express a tense, while the endings of the imperfect do express tense (even though they are always finite too). *Luoi* = "may he unbind" (optative), which can be used in present, future, or past sentences alike, i.e. there is no real tense in it.

**Aspect** can be expressed in suffixes, in (suppletive) stems, in additional words, but also in endings, if you consider something like *-bam* above to be a single morpheme.

---

In English, most endings have contracted or disappeared in ways that make different persons, moods, and numbers invisible. There is still *-s* in the 3rd person present singular indicative for most verbs, and the most important and frequent verb of all, *to be*, still has many distinctive endings; but most other Indo-European languages have many more visible endings. The "invisible endings" in English finite verbs are often called *zero endings*, an kind of *zero inflexion*.

Because of this, many linguists have resorted to using the present tense v. the (synthetic) past tense as a more practical way of distinguishing between finite and non-finite forms. English doesn't really have endings that can be conveniently separated from tense, so a problem as with the Greek optative endings above (which have no tense) does not occur in English. So a way to test whether a verb form is a finite form or not is by testing whether it can be put in the (synthetic) past tense and present tense without changing the structure of the sentence. *He goes to school => he went to school*: that is possible, so it must be a finite form.

Comment: There are some languages which have an infinitive which is not the basic form of the verb but is derived from it by inflections such as changing the ending. No example of the top of my head though sorry. Oh I wrote that before seeing you state a difference between *endings* and *suffixes* I had never heard before - but I have no formal linguistics training. I also hadn't come across *contraction* used for the combination of verbal categories that go into a suffix or ending before.

Comment: I've not encountered this distinction before, and I find your use of the words rather unhelpful.

Comment: @ColinFine: Which distinction and which words, exactly?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear: I was appending this to hippietrail's comment, and means _ending_ vs _suffix_. In any given discussion one might reasonably use them distinctively, but I have not met the particular distinction you are making.

Comment: @ColinFine: So what are you suggesting? I've heard different people make all sorts of distinctions. Last time I discussed this with a linguist, he insisted on only calling derivational suffixes suffixes, but I've seen many other categorizations. Are you suggesting that any kind of suffix should be called an ending as well? So then the scope of *finite* no longer matches *ending*? Or what definitions do you use?

Comment: I did some hunting around and indeed I did find that *ending* has a special use as described that I was hitherto unaware of. I find it counterintuitive and a bit annoying but that's the terminology we've inherited so the best we can do is know the quirks of the jargon of our field.

Comment: If this terminology is troublesome then it surely makes a great candidate for its own question so other interested parties will have a place to find a specific answer. In particular I find it surprising that the Anglo-Saxon term *ending* the more specific technial sense than the Romance term *suffix* - it's usually the other way around.

Comment: @hippietrail: Well, the reason is that finite means literally "having an ending", and we all know infinitives are non-finite.

Comment: I always thought of *finite* as meaning something like "tied to a specific time". There are languages in which the infinitive is derived from some other basic form by adding an ending. If that would be termed "adding a suffix" instead due to the set definition of *ending* then I would regard that as unclear and unfortunate terminology.

Comment: @hippietrail: I understand why you're coming from, which is why I said, "although one might question the rationale behind this." The problem is that *finite* literally means "having an end(ing)", as you know, and *infinite* "not having an ending". That how these words came to be. So I don't really see a way around it if you want to apply this terminology rigorously and consistently. Of course no puppies (little Cerberi!) die if you use the words differently. But, if you would like to have a word that includes both finite and infinite forms, why not use *suffix*, then?

Comment: P.S. Do you consider *-able* an ending? Or a suffix? Is it more like *-s* or more like infinitive endings? // You say, *"There are languages in which the infinitive is derived from some other basic form by adding an ending."* That is absolutely true, but the same applies to *any* suffix or ending. German inf. *seh-en*, 3rd pers. sg. *sieht*, noun *sehung*, etc. // Note that finite verbs can be tenseless, like the Greek subjunctive and optative; and non-finite forms can have a temporal reference, like the English past participle. So "finite" really isn't named after being "tied to a time".

Comment: P.P.S. Note also that nominals can also have endings. The suffixes that mark case, number, and/or sex are also called endings, like English plural *-s* or Dutch *-e* in many adjectives or Latin *-a* in *femina*.

Comment: I never thought of the literal meaning of *infinite* to be lacking and *ending* but to be lacking *limits*. I can see thinking of the linguistic sense being about lack of ending can be a handy mnemonic, and now that I think about it *infinite* might have that meaning etymologically or in Latin, which I suppose is what you mean. I wouldn't characterise that as the literal English meaning of *infinite* though, it's become opaque to English speakers, or at least to this one (-:

Comment: P.S. This is quite a fascinating discussion. It seems Wiktionary is also confused. **infinitive** **1.** Indefinably large, countlessly great; immense. [from 14th c.] **6.** (grammar) Not limited by person or number. [from 19th c.] --- To my native speaker intuition their sense 1. is the "literal" meaning. Their sense 6. matches how I thought about the linguistic meaning. But Wiktionary is written by amatuer volunteers so it would be interesting to also look at some big print dictionaries...

Comment: @hippietrail: For an example of a language which has an infinitive which is not the most basic form of the verb, Japanese and all other Japonic languages work. In modern standard Japanese, for instance, the most basic form of the verb is the verb stem plus the imperfective suffix. For instance, *ik-u* `|go-IPFV|` versus *ik-i* `|go-INF|`. The situation in Okinawan and other Japonic is similar, though the citation form of verbs appears to be the final predicative form (which Japanese no longer distinguishes): *ʔicu-n* `|go.IPFV-FIN|` versus *ʔic-i* `|go-INF|`.

Comment: Why are infinitives considered non-finite when they do change form in the passive voice and the perfect construction?

Answer (score 0):

In Latin grammar the term "finite verbform"  means the use of this verbform is limited to the use with a subject or a pronoun of the first or second or third person.
Infinite verbforms as infinitive, participles or gerunds don't have this limited use. They are not connected with a subject or
personal pronouns.